# How to access default implementation in category?

Tags: ios, iphone

In inheritance we used to call `[super methodName]` to call default implementation.

Like wise: How to access default implementation in category?

Comment: why do you need default implementation on category? category generally used for adding some additional functionalities to the existing class..You better to use inheritance for default implementation purpose.

Comment: Take for an example you have an UIAlertView which needs to be handled via bluetooth External keyboard, On -[UIAlertview show] method i need to write some additional handling code along with default functionality which I m doing with use of categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The categories do not allow accessing default implementation. Possible solution can be achieved with [method swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/MethodSwizzling). Using that approach you can change selectors mapping in runtime and call default mapped implementation whenever you need.